# bring the str1 to str2 in minimum operations

Tags: java

I got a job from my teacher.
I need to get two strings str1 and str2 and bring the str1 to str2 in minimum operations.
I was able to write a code and it works great but I did not really succeed according to the teacher's requests.
He wants the method call "public static int edit (String str1, String str2)"

And the method I did is:
public static int edit (String str1, String str2, int m, int n)

I can not think of a solution without using m and n, I would be happy to help.

```
    public  static int min(int x,int y,int z)
{
    if (x<=y && x<=z) return x;
    if (y<=x && y<=z) return y;
    else return z;
}

static int edit(String str1 , String str2)
{
    // If first string is empty, the only option is to
// insert all characters of second string into first
if (str1.length() == 0) return str1.length();

// If second string is empty, the only option is to
// remove all characters of first string
if (str1.length()-1 == 0) return str1.length();

// If last characters of two strings are same, nothing
// much to do. Ignore last characters and get count for
// remaining strings.
if (str1.charAt(str1.length()-1) == str2.charAt(str2.length()-1))
    return edit(str1, str2, str1.length, str2.length());

// If last characters are not same, consider all three
// operations on last character of first string, recursively
// compute minimum cost for all three operations and take
// minimum of three values.
return 1 + min ( edit(str1, str2, str1.length, str2.length()-1), // Insert
                edit(str1, str2, str1.length-1, str2.length()), // Remove
                edit(str1, str2, str1.length-1, str2.length()-1) // Replace                  
            );
}
```

Comment: Or you can make your method as private static and call that inside your `public static int edit(...)` like : `public static int edit ( String str1, String str2 ) { return edit( str1, str2, str1.length(), str2.length() ); }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a new method?

```
public static int edit(String str1, String str2) {
    return edit(str1, str2, str1.length(), str2.length());
}
```

This is sometimes called a driver method.

Comment: thanks for your comment , But it's still doesn't working please look on my code

Comment: You don't need to change any of your code you just write a new method.